# Amazon Redshift to Glacier

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, amazon-glacier

I would like to backup a snapshot of my Amazon Redshift cluster into Amazon Glacier.

I don't see a way to do that using the API of either Redshift or Glacier. I also don't see a way to export a Redshift snapshot to a custom S3 bucket so that I can write a script to move the files into Glacier.

Any suggestion on how I should accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

There is no function in Amazon Redshift to export data directly to Amazon Glacier.

[Amazon Redshift snapshots](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-snapshots.html), while stored in Amazon S3, are only accessible via the Amazon Redshift console for restoring data back to Redshift. The snapshots are not accessible for any other purpose (eg moving to Amazon Glacier).

The closest option for moving data from Redshift to Glacier would be to use the Redshift [UNLOAD](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html) command to export data to files in Amazon S3, and then to [lifecycle](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) the data from S3 into Glacier.

Alternatively, simply **keep the data in Redshift snapshots**. Backup storage beyond the provisioned storage size of your cluster and backups stored after your cluster is terminated are billed at standard [Amazon S3 rates](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/). This has the benefit of being easily loadable back into a Redshift cluster. While you'd be paying slightly more for storage (compared to Glacier), the real cost saving is in the convenience of quickly restoring the data in future.

Answer (score 0):

Any use case to take a backup as Redshift automatically keeps snapshots. Here is a reference [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/working-with-snapshots.html)